# Некорректно обрабатывается событие на чекбоксе после выгрузки из localstorage

Tags: javascript, html5

Всем здравствуйте. Благодаря подсказке из своего прошлого вопроса научился при нажатии на `checkbox` удалять строку таблицы, в котором он находился. Но моя задача усложнилась - после каждой манипуляции я загружаю актуальную таблицу в `localstorage`. С этим все ОК. Далее я обновляю страницу и забираю из хранилища свою таблицу (ну чтобы данные не потерялись) - тут тоже все супер. Но событие на `checkbox` при этом теряется и я пытаюсь объявить его снова с помощью той же конструкции, которая успешно срабатывает при добавлении элементов таблицу. Вот этот кусочек:

```
 var ShoppingList = localStorage.getItem('ShoppingList'); //тут я получаю всю табличку
    if (ShoppingList !== null) {
        document.getElementById('myTable').innerHTML = ShoppingList;
    }
        var checkbox = document.getElementById('checkbox_id'); //тут я получаю конкретно чекбокс
    checkbox.addEventListener("click", function (elemCheck) { // ну а тут я вроде как должен присвоить ему событие
        var checkboxElement = elemCheck.target;
        var elCheck = checkboxElement.parentElement.parentElement;
        elCheck.parentElement.removeChild(elCheck);
        localStorage.setItem("ShoppingList", document.getElementById("myTable").innerHTML); // и кладу обратно в хранилище
    });
```

Но после `F5` первая строка таблицы удаляется, а на остальных кликанье по чекбоксу ни к чему не приводит. Почему так происходит? В чем мой косяк? Уже совсем запутался. Подскажите пожалуйста. Более полный листинг прилагаю. Спасибо.

```js
function insertRow(id) {
  var tbody = document.getElementById(id).getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
  var row;
  row = document.createElement("tr");
  row.setAttribute("id", "tr_id");
  var cellCounter = document.getElementById("myTable").rows.length;

  var td1 = document.createElement("td");
  td1.setAttribute("id", "td1_id");
  td1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cellCounter));

  var td2 = document.createElement("td");
  td2.setAttribute("id", "td2_id");
  var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
  checkbox.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
  checkbox.setAttribute("id", "checkbox_id");
  checkbox.addEventListener("click", function(elemCheck) {
    var checkboxElement = elemCheck.target;
    var elCheck = checkboxElement.parentElement.parentElement;
    elCheck.parentElement.removeChild(elCheck);
    localStorage.setItem("ShoppingList", document.getElementById("myTable").innerHTML);
  });
  td2.appendChild(checkbox);

  var td3 = document.createElement("td");
  td3.setAttribute("id", "td3_id");
  td3.appendChild(document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("add_id").value));

  var td4 = document.createElement("td");
  td4.setAttribute("id", "td4_id");
  td4.appendChild(document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("quant_id").value));

  var td5 = document.createElement("td");
  td5.setAttribute("id", "td5_id");
  td5.appendChild(document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("price_id").value));

  var td6 = document.createElement("td");
  td6.setAttribute("id", "td6_id");
  var btnEdit = document.createElement("input");
  btnEdit.setAttribute("class", "btnEdit");
  btnEdit.src = "icons/edit.png";
  btnEdit.type = "image";
  btnEdit.addEventListener('click', function() {
    editButton();
    return false;
  });
  td6.appendChild(btnEdit);

  var deleteButton = document.createElement("input");
  deleteButton.setAttribute("class", "deleteButton");
  deleteButton.src = "icons/delete.png";
  deleteButton.type = "image";
  deleteButton.addEventListener('click', function(elemDel) {
    var deleteElement = elemDel.target;
    var elDel = deleteElement.parentElement.parentElement;
    elDel.parentElement.removeChild(elDel);
    localStorage.setItem("ShoppingList", document.getElementById("myTable").innerHTML);
  });
  td6.appendChild(deleteButton);
  td6.setAttribute("colspan", "2");
  row.appendChild(td1);
  row.appendChild(td2);
  row.appendChild(td3);
  row.appendChild(td4);
  row.appendChild(td5);
  row.appendChild(td6);
  tbody.appendChild(row);

  localStorage.setItem("ShoppingList", document.getElementById("myTable").innerHTML);
}

function indexLS() {
  var ShoppingList = localStorage.getItem('ShoppingList');
  if (ShoppingList !== null) {
    document.getElementById('myTable').innerHTML = ShoppingList;
  }
  var checkbox = document.getElementById('checkbox_id');
  checkbox.addEventListener("click", function(elemCheck) {
    var checkboxElement = elemCheck.target;
    var elCheck = checkboxElement.parentElement.parentElement;
    elCheck.parentElement.removeChild(elCheck);
    localStorage.setItem("ShoppingList", document.getElementById("myTable").innerHTML);
  });

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Cart</title>
</head>

<body onload="indexLS();return false;" class="body">
  <div class="menu">
    <ul class="list">
      <li class="li_index"><a class="link_index" href="index.html">Shopping list</a></li>
      <li class="li"><a class="link" href="done.html">Done</a></li>
      <li class="li"><a class="link" href="deleted.html">Deleted</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <h1 class="h1">Shopping List</h1>
    <hr class="hr">
    <div class="inputs">
      <input class="input_add" type="text" id="add_id" placeholder="Add items to you Shopping List">
      <input class="input_quant" type="text" id="quant_id" placeholder="Quant.">
      <input class="input_price" type="text" id="price_id" placeholder="Price">
      <button class="input_button" type="button" onclick="insertRow('myTable');return false;">Add</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="table">
    <table class="mytable" id="myTable" cellspacing="0" border="1">
      <tbody id="tbody">
        <tr id="tr_id" class="tr">
          <td>#</td>
          <td>Done</td>
          <td>Item</td>
          <td>Quantity</td>
          <td>Price $</td>
          <td colspan="2" width="100">Action</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

</body>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала хочу дать тебе небольшой совет - не нужно недооценивать `console.log`, если что-то идет не так, проверяй в консоли все переменные и данные, которые вызывают сомнения. Например вот в этой строке ты получаешь не все чекбоксы, то только первый в списке элементов с одинаковыми `id`:

```
//так все элементы на странице не получить.
var checkbox = document.getElementById('checkbox_id');
```

Немного отрефакторил твой код, постарался сделать его более читаемым и исправил многократное повторение одного и того же куска кода. Ну и все работает, конечно.

```js
function insertRow(id) {

  // зачем при поиске таблицы было вот это - .getElementsByTagName("tbody")
  //[0]??? У тебя на странице не должно быть двух одинаковых id(!),
  // значит не надо дополнительные селекторы вводить, учись работать с
  //классами и коллекциями элементов.
  // Сразу определяем все основные переменные.
  var tbody = document.getElementById(id),
    row = document.createElement('tr'),
    cellCounter,
    shopItem = document.getElementById('add_id').value,
    quant = document.getElementById("quant_id").value,
    price = document.getElementById("price_id").value;

  var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
  checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
  checkbox.className = 'checkbox_done';

  var btnEdit = document.createElement("input");
  btnEdit.type = 'button';
  btnEdit.className = 'btnEdit';
  btnEdit.value = 'Edit';

  var btnDelete = document.createElement("input");
  btnDelete.type = 'button';
  btnDelete.className = 'deleteButton';
  btnDelete.value = 'Delete';

  //делаем проверку полей на заполненность, чтобы нельзя было создавать пустые строки
  // если хоть одно поле не заполнено - не делаем вообще ничего
  if (shopItem.replace(/[\s]+/g, '') === '' || quant.replace(/[\s]+/g, '') === '' || price.replace(/[\s]+/g, '') === '') return;

  //проверяем, есть ли в таблице ячейки с id товара,
  //если нет, то id равен 1
  if (document.getElementsByClassName('item_id').length === 0) {

    cellCounter = 1;

  } else { //в противном случае мы берем последний id и увеличиваем его

    var item = document.getElementsByClassName('item_id'),
      lastIndex = item.length - 1,
      lastId = item[lastIndex].innerHTML;

    cellCounter = parseInt(lastId) + 1;
  }

  //теперь создаем ячейки и добавляем в них все что нужно
  var tdId = document.createElement('td');
  tdId.className = 'item_id';
  tdId.innerHTML = cellCounter;

  var tdDone = document.createElement('td');
  tdDone.className = 'done';
  tdDone.appendChild(checkbox);

  var tdItem = document.createElement('td');
  tdItem.className = 'item_shop';
  tdItem.innerHTML = shopItem;

  var tdQuant = document.createElement('td');
  tdQuant.className = 'quantity';
  tdQuant.innerHTML = quant;

  var tdPrise = document.createElement('td');
  tdPrise.className = 'price';
  tdPrise.innerHTML = price;

  var tdAction = document.createElement('td');
  tdAction.className = 'action';
  tdAction.appendChild(btnEdit);
  tdAction.appendChild(btnDelete);

  row.appendChild(tdId);
  row.appendChild(tdDone);
  row.appendChild(tdItem);
  row.appendChild(tdQuant);
  row.appendChild(tdPrise);
  row.appendChild(tdAction);

  tbody.appendChild(row);

  //вызываем колбэк, добавляющий таблицу в localStorage
  addStorage('ShoppingList', document.getElementById("myTable").innerHTML);

  //и колбэк, овечающий за работу с коллекцией чекбоксов
  identCheck();

};

//Функция удаления строк. Переиспользуемый компонент! можешь применять в любой таблице.
function deleteRow(elemCheck) {

  var checkboxElement = elemCheck.target;
  var elCheck = checkboxElement.parentElement.parentElement;
  elCheck.parentElement.removeChild(elCheck);

  addStorage('ShoppingList', document.getElementById("myTable").innerHTML);

}

//Снова переиспользуемый компонент, это сейчас тут у тебя сохранение в
//localStorage,
//а могут быть и сложные обращения к серверу. Такие вещи всегда выноси в
//отдельные функции.
function addStorage(nameStorage, contentsStorage) {

  localStorage.setItem(nameStorage, contentsStorage);

};


//Обработка коллекции элементов, легко расширяется до переиспользуемого добавлением аргументов.
function identCheck() {
  var checkbox = document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox_done');

  [].forEach.call(checkbox, function(el) {

    el.addEventListener('click', deleteRow, false);

  });

};

//дергаем таблицу из локалСторедж и запускаем цепочку обработчиков чекбоксов
function indexLS() {

  var ShoppingList = localStorage.getItem('ShoppingList');

  if (ShoppingList == null) {
    return;
  }

  document.getElementById('myTable').innerHTML = ShoppingList;

  identCheck();

};

//дожидаемся полной загрузки страницы и вызываем нужную функцию отрисовки аблицы из временного хранилища
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', indexLS, false);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Cart</title>
</head>

<body class="body">
  <div class="menu">
    <ul class="list">
      <li class="li_index"><a class="link_index" href="index.html">Shopping list</a></li>
      <li class="li"><a class="link" href="done.html">Done</a></li>
      <li class="li"><a class="link" href="deleted.html">Deleted</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <h1 class="h1">Shopping List</h1>
    <hr class="hr">
    <div class="inputs">
      <input class="input_add" type="text" id="add_id" placeholder="Add items to you Shopping List">
      <input class="input_quant" type="text" id="quant_id" placeholder="Quant.">
      <input class="input_price" type="text" id="price_id" placeholder="Price">
      <button class="input_button" type="button" onclick="insertRow('myTable');return false;">Add</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="table">
    <table class="mytable" id="myTable" cellspacing="0" border="1">
      <tbody id="tbody">
        <tr id="tr_id" class="tr">
          <td>#</td>
          <td>Done</td>
          <td>Item</td>
          <td>Quantity</td>
          <td>Price $</td>
          <td colspan="2" width="100">Action</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

</body>
<script src="js.js"></script>

</html>
```

Код на **codepen**: https://codepen.io/Firwolf/pen/qpNwbX

**P.S.** Практика - это очень хорошо, но и про теорию нельзя забывать, почитай про поиск элементов, про работу с событиями. Это для начала. И конечно понадобятся знания работы с объектами и массивами, без этого будет сложно на первых этапах.

**UPD**
В ответ на комментарий про пересчет строк - если нужно, чтобы при удалении произвольной строки происходил пересчет всех строк, то нужно вызывать перерисовку таблицы. Начнем с того, что это уже будет не `id` товара, а просто порядковый номер строки. Чтобы выполнить такую задачу, придется переписать логику. Раз уж ты взялся учить `JS`, думаю, будет не очень честно просто написать скрипт за тебя, но вот примерный порядок действий:

1. При нажатии на кнопку `Add` нужно формировать объект с данными, полученными из `input'ов`, добавлять объект в массив и записывать этот массив в базу (в твоем случае `localStorage`). *Важно! `id` объекта должен так же формироваться, но он должен быть полностью уникальным для каждого товара. Его можно будет с  охранять в таблице в `data`-параметр ячейки, например с названием товара.*
2. Далее должен запускаться скрипт, который будет получать сохраненный массив из `localStorage`, пробегать по нему и в каждую строку сохранять объект, раскидывая значения свойств по ячейкам. Чтобы получить порядковый номер строки, нужно так же циклом пробегать по `lenght` массива со счетчиком начинающимся с 1 и по порядку добавлять в соответствующую ячейку. Этот скрипт должен вызываться как при нажатии `Add`, так и при загрузке страницы.
3. При выборе чекбокса на удаление, нужно получить `id` товара из `data`, который мы сохранили при отрисовке таблицы, пробежать по сохраненному массиву и найти соответствующий объект по этому `id`, удалить его, сохранить измененный массив в `localStorege` и снова вызвать скрипт из пункта 2.

Будет что-то непонятно - спрашивай. Ну и постарайся писать несколько небольших, но используемых несколько раз, функций, вместо громоздких конструкций, выполняющих кучу разных действий.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ваши рекомендации, постараюсь впредь их учитывать. Возможно я взялся за выполнение достаточно сложной задачи в рамках первой практики... Хотя, с другой стороны, за время ее выполнения я узнал столько, сколько не узнал бы за месяцы сухой теории.

Comment: @TheHateInMe все правильно, просто параллельно нужно еще изучать теорию. Так сказать в свободное от практики время)

Comment: помогите исправить счетчик cellCounter в вашем примере. При добавлении нумерация проставляется верно, но если удалить строку в середине таблицы, то номер станет просто пропущен,вместо того чтобы произвелся новый пересчет....

Comment: @TheHateInMe дополнил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо! На первый взгляд все понятно, вечером попробую реализовать.